# How to solve this complicated truss system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, applied-mechanics, stresses, statics

Below is a truss I simulated in a truss calculator. I'm just wondering, how to solve for the compression and tension of each member and are there any method that can solve this?

My solution is I consider the left and right support forces, however I only arrived at 3 equations with 4 unknowns which cannot be solved.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check to see if it statically determinant?  usually trusses are built of of triangular sections and you have a four sided section right in the middle of the truss.  Since Truss nodes are considered pins, this truss is unstable.

Comment: @ForwardEd , I see. So, why can the truss calculator calculate if it is unstable ?

Comment: it is stable due to the constraints.  both points 0 and 4 are prevented from moving in both x and y.

Comment: are you sure it wouldn't deform the 1-8-9-10 quadrilateral?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14323/how-to-calculate-indeterminacy-of-pin-jointed-frame?rq=1).  It should shed some light on determinant and indeterminant trusses.  Note indeterminant does not mean unstable.

Comment: I agree. It doesn't look unstable to me from a purely analytical point of view. It does, however, look indeterminate. Member deformations must be considered.

Comment: For both ends pinned, the truss is structurally independent to the first degree, you can't treat it as a simply supported structure.

Comment: Suggest releasing the horizontal support at one end to get lateral displacement, then use the unit load/dummy load method to solve the external support reactions and internal member forces.

Answer (score 0):

Method I like to use is one that breaks trusses up into simpler trusses.

For this problem start at a truss formed by points 1, 8, 10, and 12.  These points are constrained like your points 1 and 4.  Load at 1 is given.  Solve for the 3 members (T17, T19, T13).

Now that you have loads for those, continue on in the same way.  Just don't forget to consider the members you have already calculated as load contributions and always consider everything connected to a single node at a time.

The final result is then determined by method of ***superimposition*** of these simpler truses.  That is the actual load is the sum of forces at each node as contributed by each member connected to that node and as such must sum to 0.  But what's really interesting is that the summing applies to the truss members too!

In other words, the given truss system is the end goal and you add sub truss systems until you reach it.

Answer (score 0):

You use Bow's notation (assign a letter to each space in the truss and between each force) and then construct a Cremona diagram. These are rather elegant, basically a method of superimposing all the joint diagrams onto one plot

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cremona_diagram

This method doesn't seem to be widely taught any more, possibly because it is slightly more difficult to teach than the simpler and more laborious methods.

However it looks to me as though that truss would collapse with a hinge at 8, in reality if not in theory.

And here you are, the first time I've done one in 40 years! The length of each line is the force in the member that separates the two regions.

[image: Hand drawn cremona diagram]